# Qutrits and spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

Please I have a problem:
When dealing with qutrits as three level systems, is it not appropriate to use spin $S=1$ operators to describe the qutrit system?
I have read somewhere that it is not appropriate to describe a qutrit using these operators, and I don't understand why. I am used to find this representation in the literature and I don't understand the above issue.

Can you please help me clarifying this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In a qutrit you should be able to access transitions between any two of the states.  You cannot do this with spin operators: you can verify for yourself that no combination of $S_x,S_y$ or $S_z$, or combination of $S_+,S_-,S_z$ can connect - say - the states $\vert 1\rangle$ and $\vert 2\rangle$ only, without including $\vert 3\rangle$.  This follows immediately from
\begin{align}
S_-=\sqrt{2}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad S_+=(S_-)^\dagger
\end{align}
so you cannot construct the operator
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
for instance, which would only connect states $\vert 1\rangle$ and $\vert 2\rangle$.

Clearly there are $6$ possible pairs of states in a $3$-level system, so you need $6$ off-diagonal operators.  In addition, you also need $3$ diagonal operators for a total of $9$.

These $9$ operators are spanned by several sets of matrices.  One example is the Gell-Mann matrices plus the identity matrix.  Another very useful set is obtained using the [generalized Pauli matrices](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.528006?casa_token=3vyfdFmgqhQAAAAA:P7cLWuDctF4keA8VYMKDGXT715-e38Tmk9OPcemG8fCdMB_cjgPu7Qwx_AYisIwqrcKy7k-C1g) and closely related to the [clock and shift matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices).

Comment: Thank you for clarifications.

Comment: So, if I may understand well enough, a spin 1 system can not be called a qutrit ??

Comment: it is not a “full” qutrit in the usual sense, although some authors will (incorrectly IMO) use qutrit for any 3-level system.  See for instance https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Carlos-Saavedra-4/publication/235004327_Qutrit_quantum_computer_with_trapped_ions/links/00b49517b1476b11fd000000/Qutrit-quantum-computer-with-trapped-ions.pdf